# Git checkout fails on untracked working tree files after git mv

Tags: git-checkout, git-mv

I have a problem with my local branches. When I am trying to do `git checkout <branch>` I get this error message:

```
error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by checkout:
... (list of files)
Please move or remove them before you switch branches.
Aborting
```

I think that the reason is a fact, that in current branch I've renamed/moved some files with `git mv`.
All the files listed in this error message are listed with old path (i.e. path before moving / renaming action). Is there any way to work around this problem? I'd like to move to my master branch now, and merge it with current branch, so after that there should be no problem, yet for now, I don't know how to successfully switch branches (and then do a merge, if there might again be some problems).

---

Edit:
I was able to checkout using -f option, but the problem remains, because now I can't do merge, for the same reasons (actually, now the paths are the opposite, i.e. now error message contains new paths, that were used in database branch) and I don't know an option to force git to do this merging.

I am not sure, but probably the same solution would work for both checkout and merge problem.

---

Following @LutzBüch comment, I am trying to show exactly what happened in this repo.
I have branches **master** and **database**. The database branch worked only on a parts strictly related to database only. This part of code remained in a directory named let's say `db`. At some point, I had to change this dir name to `DB`, so I did some `git mv`'s. Let's follow it from last merge, when everything still worked.

```
git checkout master
git merge database
git checkout database
git commit

{now the renaming happens}
git mv db/. tmp/.
git mv tmp/. DB/.
git commit {no other changes were made}
{added some renaming related changes, i.e. changed paths in 2 files}
git commit --amend

{now it's becoming the standard}
git commit {multiple times}
git checkout master {fails}
```

Last command failed with error message mentioned earlier. All files on the list had paths with the old dirname, i.e. `db`. After using `git checkout -f master`, when I tried to do merge I received paths with `DB` as the dirname.

Comment: Can you provide a more concrete description with an `ls` of the respective working trees of both branches?

Comment: It was quite simple renaming through git. Now that I think about it, it is just a case-sensitivity change and that might be a problem. So as you ask for `ls` it would be simply `Aa/.` in master (where I moved with force option) vs `AA/.` in a the branch i want to merge.